# Sorting a generic array of elements in Java

Tags: java, sorting, generics

I have a generic class in my Java program, and the type can either be Double or Integer. I need to write a function that first needs to sort an array of values of the generic type. I am getting the following exception, and I am unsure how to fix it. I would appreciate any help.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:290)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:157)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
    at datastructures.CircularBuffer.getMedian(CircularBuffer.java:98)
    at test.CircularBufferTests.test4(CircularBufferTests.java:67)
    at test.CircularBufferTests.main(CircularBufferTests.java:13)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class CircularBuffer<T extends Number> {

private T[] array;

public CircularBuffer(int n){
        array = (T[])new Number[n];
    }

public double getMedian(int size){


        ...
            Arrays.sort(array);
        ...

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: An element of `array` is `null`. It cannot be. If you want to include `null` write a custom `Comparator` to handle it.

Comment: Check if items in your arrays are null..

Comment: can you share more of your code? its impossible to follow

Comment: @AmirAfghani of `ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending`? What's that going to tell the OP?

Comment: You are right Boris, sorry for the misleading comment

Answer (score 1):

Well obiviously there is not enough code here to understand but as for the ComparableTimSort (where the exception is actually comes from) class where you pass your T to, Not all the T types you pass (Number class) implement the Comparable interface in order to check if that is your problem try and pass you T with a Comparable cast

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a custom Comparator in order to sort using Arrays.sort().

```
Arrays.sort(array, yourComparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

1. What vhax suggested. More specifically

   ```
   Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<T>{
       @Override
       public int compare(T arg0, T arg1)
       {
           ...
       }
   });
   ```
2. What crazyPixel suggeseted, more spefically

   ```
   public class CircularBuffer<T extends Number & Comparable<T>>
   ```

This way, you are restricting on T to be more specific. This is called "multiple bounds" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Comment: When I first reviewed this I didn't understand why you were copying two different answers into a new answer (generally frowned on).  Then I checked and you were actually providing significant additional information so you get a +1